# Windows For loop command replaces comma with spaces

Tags: batch-file

I am working on windows batch script that is used to connect to Microsoft TFS to get the list of workspaces created by a particular user and got struck with the below issue.Part of the script where the issue occurs is below

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN ('CALL tf workspaces -server:%TFS_SERVER% /login:%TFS_CREDENTIAL%') DO ( 
   echo %%A
)
```

Where TFS_CREDENTIALS is username,password e.g. testuser,pwd.

Problem:

When set echo is on in the script, the command in the for loop replaces the , by space and hence the script cannot connect to TFS

```
CALL tf workspaces -server:tfsserver.com /login:testuser pwd
```

But if run the command as a separate line outside the FOR , the echo shows the command as it is.

```
CALL tf workspaces -server:tfsserver.com /login:testuser,pwd
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the commas, prefixing them with `^`. A string substitution can be enough

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (
    'tf workspaces -server:%TFS_SERVER% /login:%TFS_CREDENTIAL:,=^,%'
) DO ( 
   echo %%A
)
```

Comment: +1 , also  the whole expression can be put in double quotes (inside the needed single quotes).Though I don't think the call is necessary .

Comment: @npocmaka, thank you. I was not sure. I have no access to the command and sometimes the obvious quoting does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I can connect to TFS fine now.